# Question about composition of bounded variation functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two functions can be composed. If $f$ is continuous and bounded variation and $g$ is bounded variation, is that true $f\circ g$ is bounded variation?
As we know, if $f$ is Lipschitz, the statement is true, but I don't know if it is true for the above situation.

Comment: Consider $g(x)=\sqrt x$ and $f(x)=x^2\sin (1/x)$

Comment: For $f\circ g(x)=x\sin(1/\sqrt{x})$, I tried to pick $x_{2k}=\frac{1}{(2k\pi)^2}$ and $x_{2k-1}=\frac{1}{(2k\pi-\pi/2)^2}$, but it seems the variation will be a sum of series of the form $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$, which is not divergent.

Comment: yes you are right. Take $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and $g(x)=x^2\sin ^2(1/x)$

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, there are continuous functions $f$ and functions of bounded variation $g$ such that $f\circ g$ *is not of bounded variation*. But I think it is worth to point out that there is more which is already known on the topic of composition of functions with functions of bounded variation.

**Theorem (Josephy (1981), p. 355, theorem 4)** For a given function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, the composition $f\circ g$ is of bounded variation for all functions $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ of bounded variation if and only if $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on $[0,1]$.

**Notes**

- The fact that the domain and codomain of the functions in the statement of theorem is $[0,1]$ does not reduce its generality: every finite interval will do.
- In the same paper, theorem 3 states a necessary and sufficient  condition for a function $g$ such that $f\circ g$ is of bounded variation for each $f$ of bounded variation, and identifies the class for such functions.

[1] Josephy, Michael (1981), "*[Composing Functions of Bounded Variation](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-083-02/S0002-9939-1981-0624930-9/)*", Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 83, No. 2, pp. 354-356, MR 624930, Zbl 0475.26005.