# A clean proof of Chain rule for BV functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-derivatives

Let $u\in BV(\mathbb{R})$ then its distributional derivative $u' \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$(the space of bounded radon measures).
I am trying to prove that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, the function $f\circ u \in BV(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the chain rule $(f\circ u)'=(f'\circ u)u'$ in the sense of measures by a smoothening argument.

For $u\in BV(\mathbb{R})$, let $u^{\epsilon}$ denote its mollification, so that $\left|u^{\epsilon}\right|_{BV(\mathbb{R})}=\left|u\right|_{BV(\mathbb{R})}$ thus upto a subsequence $u^{\epsilon} \rightarrow u$ in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and ${u^{\epsilon}}' \rightarrow  u'$ in weak* $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$.

Now, consider
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (f \circ u)'= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (f \circ u^{\epsilon})'= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (f' \circ u^{\epsilon}) {u^{\epsilon}}' = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (f' \circ u) {u}' \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
which implies that the chain rule holds.
I have the follwoing doubts

1. Is the above argument correct?  especially the last equality in \eqref{1} which uses product of a weakly and strongly convergent sequence is weakly convergent
2. Can we justify the same if $f$ is only Lipschitz continuous in particular $f(x)=|x|$ and $f'(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: If $u$ is Heaviside function then $(f \circ u)' = (f(1) - f(0))\delta \neq f'(1)\delta = (f' \circ u)u'$ where $\delta$ is Dirac delta distribution.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer to question 1.

---

> 1. Is the above argument correct?  especially the last equality in \eqref{1} which uses product of a weakly and strongly convergent sequence is weakly convergent

**Yes, but I'd choose the following route to proof the result**, as it is more detailed even if more complex. Let's proceed step by step.

1. The first thing to note is that $\{(f\circ u^\varepsilon)^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] } = \{(f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] }$ is a sequence of Radon measures. Indeed
   $$
   C_c(\Bbb R)\ni\varphi\mapsto \int\limits_{\Bbb R} \varphi ( f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon ) {u^\varepsilon}^\prime \in{\Bbb R}
   $$
   is a continuous map for every $\varepsilon\in\, ]0, 1]$ since

   - $f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon(x)$ is a continuous function by construction, $\varphi(x)\cdot ( f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon)(x)$ is a continuous map from $C_c(\Bbb R)$ to itself and
   - ${u^\varepsilon}^\prime\in \mathcal{M}(\Bbb R)$ again by construction and the conclusion holds by Riesz theorem (see for example [1], §1.4, p. 26, theorem 1.54 and remark 1.57).

   **Edit**. At this point we still do not know if the sequence converges. We just know that the have a sequence of Radon measures which is obtained fro two weakly* convergent sequences of Radon measures: we have not used this latest fact and, as we'll see, we will not use it in the following step.

   **Second edit** I am not sure that the argument used for this part of the answer is entirely correct. In particular, thinking about the bound \eqref{bd}, I doubt it is effective. I do not delete the entire answer just because the second part is correct and it includes also the case when $f\in C^1$.
2. Now recall the definition of **locally weak*** **convergence** and a lemma on the convergence of sequences of Radon measures.

   - (see [1], §1.4, p. 27, definition 1.58) Let $\mu$ and the sequence $\{\mu_h\}_{h}$ be $\Bbb R^m$-valued ($m\ge 1$) Radon measures on the locally convex separable metric space $X$; we say that *$\{\mu_h\}$ locally weakly** *converges to $\mu$* if
     $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dd}{d\!}
     \lim_{h\to\infty} \int\limits_X \varphi \Dd \mu_h =\int\limits_X \varphi \Dd \mu
     $$
     for every $\varphi \in C_c(X)$.
   - *A corollary of the classical De la Valle Pussin compactness criterion for finite Radon measures (see [1], §1.4, p. 28, corollary 1.60)*.
     If a sequence $\{\mu_h\}_{h}$ of Radon measures on a locally convex separable metric space $X$ is such that
     $$
     \sup\{|\mu_h|(K) \mid h\in\Bbb N\}<+\infty
     $$ where $\lvert\mu_h\rvert$ is the total variation of the measure $\mu_h$, and the inequality holds for every compact set $K\subset X$ then it has a locally weakly* converging subsequence.

   But then we are done, as the family $\{(f\circ u^\varepsilon)^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] } = \{(f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] }$ satisfies exactly these requirements. Indeed, choosing $\varepsilon =\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in\Bbb N$ and using Hölder's inequality we have
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \lvert u^\varepsilon(x)\rvert & = \left \lvert\int\limits_{\Bbb R} u(x-y)\nu_{1\over n}(y)\Dd y\right\rvert \\
   & = \left \lvert\int\limits_{\Bbb R} u(x-y)n \nu(ny)\Dd y\right\rvert\\
   & = \left \lvert\int\limits_{\Bbb R} u\left(x-\frac{z}{n}\right)\nu(z)\Dd z\right\rvert\\
   & \le \int\limits_{\Bbb R} \left\lvert u\left(x-\frac{z}{n}\right)\nu(z)\right\rvert\Dd z \\
   & \le \lVert u\rVert_{L^1}\lVert \nu\rVert_\infty < + \infty
   \end{split}
   $$
   i.e. the mollified version $u^\varepsilon$ of a $L^1$ function is bounded and its upper bound does not depend on the value of $\varepsilon$, thus
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \sup_{\substack{\varphi\in C_c (K)\\ \|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1}} \int\limits_K \varphi (f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime \Dd x &=  \sup_{\substack{\varphi\in C_c (K)\\ \|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1}} \int\limits_K \varphi (f\circ u^\varepsilon)^\prime\Dd x\\
   &= \sup_{\substack{\varphi\in C_c (K)\\ \|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1}}\int\limits_K \varphi^\prime (f\circ u^\varepsilon)\Dd x \\
   &\le M_f \sup_{\substack{\varphi\in C_c (K)\\ \|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1}} \int\limits_K \varphi^\prime \Dd x
   \end{split}\label{bd}\tag{BD}
   $$
   where $M_f=\sup_{|x|\le \lVert u\rVert_{L^1}\lVert \nu\rVert_\infty}f$

The formula
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(f\circ u^\varepsilon)^\prime = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} (f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime\triangleq (f\circ u)^\prime \triangleq (f^\prime\circ u)u^\prime
$$
holds true and, as stated above, we do not need the fact that the sequence $\{(f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] }$ is the product of two locally weak* convergent sequences.

### Answer to question 2.

---

> 2. Can we justify the same if $f$ is only Lipschitz continuous in particular $f(x)=|x|$ and $f'(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$.

**Yes, it may be possible to proceed as shown above**: nevertheless we can obtain the most general result  by using the classical definition of variation for functions of one real variable. Precisely, assuming that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $M>0$ i.e. $f\in C^{0,1}(\Bbb R)$ $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \le M \lvert x-y \rvert$ fro all $x,y \in\Bbb R$, we have that
$$
\begin{split}
V_a^b(f\circ u) & =\sup_{P \in \mathscr{P}} \sum_{i=0}^{n_{P}-1} | f\circ u(x_{i+1})-f\circ u(x_i)|\\
&\le M \sup_{P \in \mathscr{P}} \sum_{i=0}^{n_{P}-1} | u(x_{i+1})- u(x_i)| =M V_a^b(u)\quad \forall a, b\in \Bbb R.
\end{split}
$$
This implies that $f\circ u\in BV_\text{loc}(\Bbb R)$ thus its derivative is a Radon measure. Furthermore since $f\in C^{0,1}(\Bbb R)$ [it is also absolutely continuous, almost everywhere differentiable and essentially bounded by its Lipschitz constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties) and we can express its first derivative as
$$
(f\circ u)^\prime = (f^\prime\circ u)u^\prime
$$
since for all $\varphi \in C_c(\Bbb R)$
$$
\begin{split}
\left|\int\limits_{\Bbb R} \varphi ( f\circ u )^\prime\right| 
& = \left|\int\limits_{\Bbb R} \varphi ( f^\prime\circ u ) {u}^\prime\right|\\
& \le M \left|\int\limits_{\Bbb R} \varphi {u}^\prime\right|< +\infty
\end{split}
$$
as $u\in BV(\Bbb R)$.

**Notes**

- For the sake of completeness, as briefly shown in [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997030/question-about-composition-of-bounded-variation-functions), a deeper result is true :

  **Theorem (Josephy [2], p. 355, theorem 4)** For a given function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, the composition $f\circ g$ is of bounded variation for all functions $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ of bounded variation if and only if $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on $[0,1]$.

  The fact that the domain and codomain of the functions in the statement of theorem is $[0,1]$ does not reduce its generality: every finite interval will do.
- In the same paper, theorem 3 states a necessary and sufficient  condition for a function $g$ such that $f\circ g$ is of bounded variation for each $f$ of bounded variation, and identifies the class for such functions.

### **References**

[1]  Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, Diego Pallara, *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*, Oxford Mathematical Monographs, New York and Oxford: The Clarendon Press/Oxford University Press, New York, pp. xviii+434 (2000), ISBN 0-19-850245-1, [MR1857292](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1857292), [Zbl 0957.49001](https://zbmath.org/0957.49001).

[2] Michael Josephy, "[Composing Functions of Bounded Variation](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-083-02/S0002-9939-1981-0624930-9/)", Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 83, No. 2, pp. 354-356, (1981), [MR624930](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=624930), [Zbl 0475.26005](https://zbmath.org/0475.26005).

Comment: I apologize I may have not cured all the details as needed for the Lipschtz case: as a matter of fact, the fact that the a composition of Lipschitz function and a $BV$-function is again a $BV$-function is one of the core result of the theory. I'll try to check and correct the details if needed

Comment: Thanks for the answer..But it's not clear to me how you are justifying the product of two weak* converging sequences ...Could u please elaborate a bit...

Comment: Hi Veronica, just a few words here before I add something more to clarify this point in the answer tomorrow morning. The sequence $\{(f\circ u^\varepsilon)^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] } = \{(f^\prime\circ u^\varepsilon){u^\varepsilon}^\prime\}_{\varepsilon\in ]0, 1] }$ is a sequence of Radon measures and it doesn't really matter that each of its single term is the product of  two terms for a weakly* converging sequence of Radon measures (note that this last fact is not used for the proof).

Comment: ...Continue fro the previous comment. The crucial step in the proof is noting that this sequence has a variation which is bounded and thus its convergence follows from the corollary of the theorem of De La Valée Pussin. I do not tried to prove that the product of two weakly* convergent sequences of Radon measures is weakly* convergent because in this case there are obvious difficulties in dealing with the algebraic side of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and updating ur answer..I am sorry but I am not convinced yet. The corollary u mentioned only assures that the sequence of measures converges to some measure (say $mu$)but what assures that this measure is indeed a product of a function $f'(u)$ and a measure $u'$

Comment: @Veronica, thank you for your patience. I am not convinced: currently I trust only for second part ($f\in C^{0,1}(\Bbb R)$). I'll try to see if the first part is salvageable or not. I should add that the a proof of the $C^1$ case in dimension $N>1$ is included in an old paper of Vol'pert while the general multidimensional Lipschitz case is proved in the book of Ambrosio et al

Comment: @Veronica I think I have a different nice route to the proof of part one, and I need some time to adjust the details.

Comment: Thank you.. Take the time you need to refine the details, and I look forward to seeing more about your alternative approach